# How do i save jpa @OneToOne/@OneToMany with auto-generated id?

Tags: java, jpa

I want a save entity with related entities.

This is my entities.

**UserEntity.java**

```
@entity
public class UserEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "uid")
    private int uid;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_uid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private ProductEntity productEntity;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_uid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<SalesEntity> list;
}
```

**ProductEntity.java**

```
@entity
public class ProductEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "uid")
    private int uid;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "user_uid")
    private int userUid;
}
```

**SalesEntity.java**

```
@entity
public class SalesEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "uid")
    private int uid;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "user_uid")
    private int userUid;
}
```

I want save UserEntity and ProductEntity, SalesEntity list once.

And I can save all data using **userRepository.save(userEntity)**.

But, UserEntity.uid(Generated Value) is not inserted in ProductEntity and SalesEntity. **Inserted with 0.**

How can i insert auto-generated-id to cascaded entities?

Comment: Use `Integer`, not `int`. The value `null` indicates "not set".